# React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> is underlined in red

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm using SVG files in my react app. When I use the following code:

```js
function Home(props: React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>) {...........}
```

the `React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>` is underlined in red.

Here's a photo:

[image]

Comment: can you create a codesandbox and reproduce this issue ?

Comment: i have created the codesandbox. Include your changes here - https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-architecture-t611d?file=/src/App.tsx